# Who is Jesus's "God"?

Tags: translation-philosophy, kjv

What God is Jesus speaking of in these passages? How can God have a God?

> Revelation 3:12 (KJV)
>   Him that overcometh will I make a pillar in the temple of my God, and he shall go no more out: and I will write upon him the name of my God, and the name of the city of my God, which is new Jerusalem, which cometh down out of heaven from my God: and I will write upon him my new name.
>
> John 20:17 (KJV)
>   Jesus saith unto her, Touch me not; for I am not yet ascended to my Father: but go to my brethren, and say unto them, I ascend unto my Father, and your Father; and to my God, and your God.

Comment: @Pascal'sWager Please don't use the comment section for mini-answers. They should be reserved for requesting clarifications or suggesting improvements to posts.

Comment: *How can God have a God ?* - Why wouldn't God have a God ?

Comment: Eric. Do you understand how you are constituted. Is your body Eric Ross? Are the thoughts in your mind Eric Ross? Or perhaps the desires of your heart? You are a triune being and your desires are superior to your mind and your body. Your mind and your body are your heart's lackeys. When you get a handle on how you are put together your dilemma concerning the nature of God will disappear.

Comment: @enegue  That sounds like "multiple personality disorder" to me. Is God "beside himself"? Is your breath (aka "spirit") a separate person from you? Are you numerically three? How many times are you charged at a buffet?

Comment: @Ruminator As usual, you give very little thought to anything I say. A "person" is numerically "one", which is why it is ridiculous to speak of "three **persons** of the trinity. The "form/body" you see, is not "the person". God can manifest in whatever "form" suits His purposes: a man; a lamb with seven horns and seven eyes; a spirit that indwells each believer; Please don't let my thoughts disturb your belief that Jesus is just another man.

Comment: So are you saying that God is in parts?

Comment: @enegue I dont understand why saying that Jesus is not equal with the Father denotes him to any ordinary man it is clear he came from heaven... and also it is clear that God has given him a name above every other name... the problem is the word given and received which Christ uses... God cannot be given anything, but if Christ emptied himself then had to be given what was already his, I could see that, except wouldn't it be clear that he wasn't receiving it for the first time? Jesus says "glorify me with the glory I had with you in the beginning"... where does it say for Him to be reinstated?

Answer (score 2):

Who is Jesus's “God”?

The Bible answers this for us.

“My God” who is He?

All texts from NWT unless noted otherwise.

To whom was Jesus calling to at:-

> Matthew 27:46
> “About the ninth hour Jesus called out with a loud voice, saying: "Eli, Eli, la´ma sabachthni?" that is, "My God, my God, why have you forsaken me?"”
>
> Which is literally rendered "this is the God of me, God of me."-'The NASB-NIV parallel N.T. in Gk. & Eng.' with Interlinear Translated by Alfred Marshall*

Who is Jesus referring to at:-

> John 20:17
> “Jesus said to her: “Stop clinging to me. For I have not yet ascended to the Father. But be on your way to my brothers and say to them, ‘I am ascending to my Father (Literal Gk. “Father of me”^) and YOUR Father and to my God (Literal Gk. “God of me”^) and YOUR God.’”
> ^'The NASB-NIV parallel N.T. in Gk. & Eng.' with Interlinear Translated by Alfred Marshall
>
> “My  poss[essive]. pron[oun]. (attrib.) 1 of or belonging to me. 2 affectionate, patronizing, etc. form of address (my dear boy). 3 in expressions of surprise (my God!; oh my!). 4 colloq. indicating a close relative etc. of the speaker (my Johnny's ill again).  my Lady (or Lord) form of address to certain titled persons. [from *mine1] .”-Oxford Dictionary
>
> “God  n[oun]. 1 a (in many religions) superhuman being or spirit worshipped as having power over nature, human fortunes, etc. b image, idol, etc., symbolizing a god. 2 (God) (in Christian and other monotheistic religions) creator and ruler of the universe. 3 adored or greatly admired person. … .”-Oxford Dictionary

Jesus must have been calling to the Almighty, the Father, his God, see John 20:17, “my God”, (Lit. Gk. "God of me" 'The NASB-NIV parallel N.T. in Gk. & Eng.' with Interliner Translated by Alfred Marshall) quoting from Ps 22:1 where King David was, showing that God is somone other than himself. No, Jesus cannot be Almighty God if he plainly says in the above texts that he himself has a “God”!

We can also add to the above, the following words, where Jesus is speaking from an exulted heavenly postion:-

> Revelation 3:12-13
> "‘The one that conquers—I* will make him a pillar in the temple of my God**, and he will by no means go out [from it] anymore, and I* will write upon him the name*** of my God** and the name of the city of my God**, the new Jerusalem which descends out of heaven from my God**, and that new name of mine.  Let the one who has an ear hear what the spirit says to the congregations.’”

*Jesus Christ
**Which in litrealy rendered "the God of me."-'The NASB-NIV parallel N.T. in Gk. & Eng.' With Interliner Translated by Alfred Marshall
***Jehovah

So we can ask again, who is Jesus talking about, as it cannot be himself as he says:-

> John 10:25  "Jesus answered them: “I told you, and yet you do not believe. ***The works that I am doing in my Father’s name***, these bear witness about me."

So what is the Name of Jesus Father, the following shows:-

> 1 Chronicles 29:10-13 "**Then David praised Jehovah** before the eyes of all the congregation. David said: “May you be praised, **O Jehovah the God of Israel our FATHER**, throughout all eternity. 11 Yours, **O Jehovah, are the greatness and the mightiness and the beauty and the splendor and the majesty, for everything in the heavens and on the earth is yours.** Yours is the kingdom, **O Jehovah. You are the One exalting yourself as head over all.** 12 The riches and the glory are from you, and you rule over everything, and in your hand there are power and mightiness, and your hand is able to make great and to give strength to all. 13 And now, O our God, ***we thank you and praise your beautiful name.***

The God of Jesus, as at Micah 5:2-4

> “And thou, BethLehem Ephratah, Little to be among the chiefs of Judah! From thee to Me he cometh forth--to be ruler in Israel, And his comings forth are of old, From the days of antiquity.  3 Therefore he doth give them out till the time She who bringeth forth hath brought forth, And the remnant of his brethren return to the sons of Israel.  4 And he hath stood and delighted in the strength of Jehovah, In the excellency of ***the name of Jehovah HIS God,*** And they have remained, For now he is great unto the ends of earth.”-‘Young’s Literal Translation’

again at:-

> Psalm 89:26-29
> []  Added to show who is spoken of.
> 26 He himself [Jesus] calls out to me [Jehovah], ‘You are my [Jesus’] Father, My [Jesus’] God and the Rock of my [Jesus’] salvation.’
> 27 Also, I myself [Jehovah] shall place him [Jesus] as firstborn, The most high of the kings of the earth.
> 28 To time indefinite I [Jehovah] shall preserve my loving-kindness toward him [Jesus], And my [Jehovah’s] covenant will be faithful to him [Jesus].
> 29 And I shall certainly set up his [David’s] seed forever And his [Jesus’] throne as the days of heaven.

The according to The Bible, the answer to the question; "Who is Jesus' God?" is,  "Jehovah."

> Ephesians 5:19, 20  "Speak to one another with psalms, **praises to God**, and spiritual songs, singing and accompanying yourselves with music in your hearts **to Jehovah**, 20 always giving thanks to **our God and Father** for everything in the name of our Lord Jesus Christ."

The K.J.V. shows Jesus' mission here on earth for it says at Psalm 83:18:-

> "That men may know that thou, whose name alone is JEHOVAH, art the most high over all the earth."

Jesus let all men know who his God was: JEHOVAH.

Answer (score 0):

Jesus is speaking of **God the Father:**

> **John 17:1-6 (DRB)**  These things Jesus spoke, and lifting up his eyes to heaven, he said: **Father,** the hour is come, glorify thy Son, that thy Son may glorify thee. 2 As thou hast given him power over all flesh, that he may give eternal life to all whom thou hast given him. 3 Now this is eternal life: That they may know **thee, the only true God,** and Jesus Christ, whom thou hast sent. 4 I have glorified thee on the earth; I have finished the work which thou gavest me to do. 5 And now glorify thou me, O Father, with thyself, with the glory which I had, before the world was, with thee.

That is, יהוה (Yahweh), the God of Abraham, Isaac and Jacob. The Creator.

Almost all those who believe in the deity of Christ, that Jesus is God, believe that He **also took on a real humanity:** is a real man, who *ipso facto* has a God as other men. Those who disbelieve the Trinity usually import Unitarian notions of a unipersonal God into discussions of the Trinity and cannot fathom how someone who is God can call another One God. Sadly for them, this is what Scripture does numerous times. For example, a Scripture placed in the mouth of God the Father is said to the Son, in which He clearly addresses the Son as 'God' (Heb 1:8; 10).

The same Unitarians often confuse Jesus' words 'you are the only true God,' for what they are looking to find: 'you only are the true God.' In orthodox Christianity, each person in the Trinity is "the only true God" simply because they are God. You can't be God and not be the only true God. In addition, Scriptural convention aptly describes God in terms of just the Father, and then the Son and Spirit in terms of Him. This is because strictly speaking, the eternal Source of the Son and the Spirit is the Father. Hence, God and HIS Son, and HIS Spirit. However, the eternality and sharing of nature makes the Father, and His Son, and His Spirit, equally 'God' in this very clear sense: the sense spoken of in John 1:1-3 when St. John goes to pains to tie in the co-eternality of the Son with the Father, as well as neing excluded absolutely from Creation, when calling Him God: "In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God. The same was in the beginning with God: all things were made by Him, and without Him was made nothing that has been made."

Never forget how the same Revelation you quoted from speaks of the glorified Son of God. He is called "the First and the Last," "He who searches the hearts and minds," etc. All explicitly unique titles of God, for reasons hopefully obvious.

Comment: "The eternal source of the Son and Spirit is the Father" can you please expound on that. Are you saying that Son and Spirit came forth from the Father? So the Son and Spirit had a beginning not in their nature since they came from an eternal Spirit, but their personalities? This is what I believe.

Comment: They had an eternal, ontological origin, not beginning. The keyword in all this is the *eternal* relationship of the Father, the Son, and the Holy Ghost. In eternity there is no 'before' and 'after.' Likewise, the Father was never without the Son, and vice versa: hence, Son, and hence Father. And likewise was not without His Spirit.

Answer (score 0):

The God of Abraham, Isaac and Jakob is also the God of Jesus:

> Jhn 4:22 KJV - 22 Ye worship ye know not what: we know what we worship: for salvation is of the Jews.

To Him he prays:

> Psa 22:1-31 KJV - 1 [To the chief Musician upon Aijeleth Shahar, A Psalm of David.] My God, my God, why hast thou forsaken me? why art thou so far from helping me, and from the words of my roaring? 2 O my God, I cry in the daytime, but thou hearest not; and in the night season, and am not silent. 3 But thou art holy, O thou that inhabitest the praises of Israel. 4 Our fathers trusted in thee: they trusted, and thou didst deliver them. 5 They cried unto thee, and were delivered: they trusted in thee, and were not confounded. 6 But I am a worm, and no man; a reproach of men, and despised of the people. 7 All they that see me laugh me to scorn: they shoot out the lip, they shake the head, saying, 8 He trusted on the LORD that he would deliver him: let him deliver him, seeing he delighted in him. 9 But thou art he that took me out of the womb: thou didst make me hope when I was upon my mother's breasts. 10 I was cast upon thee from the womb: thou art my God from my mother's belly. 11 Be not far from me; for trouble is near; for there is none to help. 12 Many bulls have compassed me: strong bulls of Bashan have beset me round. 13 They gaped upon me with their mouths, as a ravening and a roaring lion. 14 I am poured out like water, and all my bones are out of joint: my heart is like wax; it is melted in the midst of my bowels. 15 My strength is dried up like a potsherd; and my tongue cleaveth to my jaws; and thou hast brought me into the dust of death. 16 For dogs have compassed me: the assembly of the wicked have inclosed me: they pierced my hands and my feet. 17 I may tell all my bones: they look and stare upon me. 18 They part my garments among them, and cast lots upon my vesture. 19 But be not thou far from me, O LORD: O my strength, haste thee to help me. 20 Deliver my soul from the sword; my darling from the power of the dog. 21 Save me from the lion's mouth: for thou hast heard me from the horns of the unicorns. 22 I will declare thy name unto my brethren: in the midst of the congregation will I praise thee. 23 Ye that fear the LORD, praise him; all ye the seed of Jacob, glorify him; and fear him, all ye the seed of Israel. 24 For he hath not despised nor abhorred the affliction of the afflicted; neither hath he hid his face from him; but when he cried unto him, he heard. 25 My praise shall be of thee in the great congregation: I will pay my vows before them that fear him. 26 The meek shall eat and be satisfied: they shall praise the LORD that seek him: your heart shall live for ever. 27 All the ends of the world shall remember and turn unto the LORD: and all the kindreds of the nations shall worship before thee. 28 For the kingdom is the LORD'S: and he is the governor among the nations. 29 All they that be fat upon earth shall eat and worship: all they that go down to the dust shall bow before him: and none can keep alive his own soul. 30 A seed shall serve him; it shall be accounted to the Lord for a generation. 31 They shall come, and shall declare his righteousness unto a people that shall be born, that he hath done this.

He obeys Him:

> 1Co 11:3 KJV - 3 But I would have you know, that the head of every man is Christ; and the head of the woman is the man; and the head of Christ is God.

He was sent to bring glory, not to himself or "the Holy Ghost" but to the Father:

> Jhn 6:38 KJV - 38 For I came down from heaven, not to do mine own will, but the will of him that sent me.
> Jhn 6:39 KJV - 39 And this is the Father's will which hath sent me, that of all which he hath given me I should lose nothing, but should raise it up again at the last day.

The refuge of Trinitarians in dealing with the scriptural identification of God as the Father is to [twist the identification by apposition into a novel, extra-Biblical and non-scriptural notion of "God the Father, God the Son and God the Spirit"](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/32970/in-philippians-211-are-god-and-the-father-used-in-apposition). This is a grotesque invention and a harsh mistreatment of the scriptures.

Yes, Jesus is a god. But so was Solomon ("thy throne O God") for he sat in the throne of Jehovah.

> 1Ch 29:23 ASV - 23 Then **Solomon sat on the throne of Jehovah as king** instead of David his father, and prospered; and all Israel obeyed him.

Joseph, another type of Christ was also promoted to be seated next to Pharaoh and drew the authority he needed to bring all of the land of Egypt under his feet. But he never crossed the line and actually had authority over the one who PUT those things under his feet:

> Act 7:10 NLT - 10 and rescued him from all his troubles. And God gave him favor before Pharaoh, king of Egypt. God also gave Joseph unusual wisdom, so that **Pharaoh appointed him governor over all of Egypt and put him in charge of the palace.**
>
> Act 2:36 NKJV - 36 "Therefore let all the house of Israel know assuredly that God has made this Jesus, whom you crucified, both Lord and Christ."
>
> Dan 7:14 NLT - 14 **He was given authority, honor, and sovereignty over all the nations of the world**, so that people of every race and nation and language would obey him. His rule is eternal--it will never end. His kingdom will never be destroyed.
>
> 1Co 15:27 NKJV - 27 For "He has put all things under His feet." But when He says "all things are put under Him," it is evident that He who put all things under Him is excepted.

The scriptures, which never mention "The Triune God" does reliably teach to keep that line intact between Jesus, the son of God, and the Father, who is the one true God.

Answer (score -1):

> What God is Jesus speaking of in these passages?

There is only one God, so it must be יהוה, the first and the last.

"This is what the LORD says-- Israel's King and Redeemer, the LORD Almighty: I am the first and I am the last; apart from me there is no God." (Isaiah 44:6)

> How can God have a God?

The [Council of Chalcedon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chalcedonian_Definition) teaches that Christ is fully human **and** fully divine. He has two natures, a human nature and a divine nature.

My favorite analogy is to imagine one person who uses both a guest account and an admin account on the computer. He is fully guest **and** fully admin. The Father, Son, and Holy Spirit all have access to the admin account, but only the Son uses the guest account. The Son can, from the guest account, send a message (prayer?) to the admin account.

This explains how Christ can both pray to God **and** be God at the same time.

Comment: Why is this so downvoted? I did not realise how many anti-trinitarians we had on here…

Comment: re: above, I just got my question closed for asking how the word "salvation" is used in the Old and New Testaments.